# Malware in phpunit folder on Cpanel

Tags: laravel-5, malware

Someone tried to hacked my website and put those file..

```
/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/cz.php
/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/fz.php 
/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/kill.php
/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/m6s.php 
/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/tz.php
```

Got any solution? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Delete The phpunit folder, it is not needed

/home/kulunghomestay/public_html/vendor/**phpunit**

Then add a .htaccess file to the vendor folder and add this

Deny from all

To deny access to files under the vendor folder